# Does (A!=B!=C) mean the same thing as (A != B or A!= C or B!=C) in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I thought in some languages doing:

```
(A1 != A2 != A3)
```

is the same thing as:

```
(A1 != A2 or A1!= A3 or A3 != A2)
```

Is that true in Oracle, as well? Or is there another way that you can accomplish this that isn't as repetitive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle the *construction* of `a1 != a2 != a3` is **not a valid predicate**

```
 select * from tst where a1 != a2 != a3;
```

gives

```
 ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

see the Oracle Syntax of the  [Comparison Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52107)

What you **could** do (and what is IMO less used in SQL) are the [**Group Comparison Conditions**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52110)

`a1 != ANY (a2,a3)` returns TRUE if the expression is TRUE for at least one element of the list

`a1 != ALL (a2,a3)` returns TRUE if the expression is TRUE for all elements of the list

Here simple examples

```
select * from tst order by a1,a2,a3;

        A1         A2         A3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1 
         1          1          2 
         1          2          1 
         1          2          2 

select * from tst where  a1 != ANY (a2,a3)  order by a1,a2,a3;

        A1         A2         A3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2 
         1          2          1 
         1          2          2 


select * from tst where  a1 != ALL (a2,a3)  order by a1,a2,a3;

        A1         A2         A3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          2
```

*The reason of the rare use is IMO in the not very intuitive appearance of those expressions. Explizite combination using `AND` and `OR` is IMO more intuitive.*

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have been doing SQL for years and was unaware of this construct.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1) `(A1 != A2 != A3)` <=> `(A1 != A2 or A1!= A3 or A3 != A2)` **is not true**

Counterexample:

```
1 != 2 != 1 
A1   A2   A3
1 != 1   (obviously false)  from equivalent form A1!= A3
```

2) You need to take to consideration `NULL`, any comparison with `NULL` value will yield `NULL`.

## EDIT

To clarify [@hvd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd):

> *This answer is incorrect. Your counterexample assumes A1 != A2 != A3 must mean one of (A1 != A2) != A3 or A1 != (A2 != A3). This is not true in all languages. The OP is correct in claiming that some languages behave differently. Example: python3.6 -c 'print(1 != 2 != 1)' prints True.*

entire `(A1 != A2 != A3) <=> (A1 != A2 or A1!= A3 or A3 != A2)` **is not tautology**

And counterexample in Python:

```
>>> print(1 != 1 != 2)
False
>>> print(1!=1 or 1!=2 or 2!=1)
True
```

It should be:

```
# A1 != A2 AND A2 != A3
>>> print(1!=1 and 1!=2)
False
```

Comment: How can you claim the two expressions are not equivalent, when the first one is not a valid syntax?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber That's another case. I wanted to point out that in general (mathematical perspective) proposed formula is not true.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda you are right, if I read the predicate in the same way as 1 < x < 3, then  `A1 != A2 != A3` would expand to `A1 != A2 and A2 != A3`

Comment: @hvd Please read carefully. I do not claim that `a1 != a2 != a3` is not true, but that it does not expand to `(A1 != A2 or A1!= A3 or A3 != A2)`. So to sum up **entire** `(A1 != A2 != A3) <=> (A1 != A2 or A1!= A3 or A3 != A2)` is not tautology.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Oh, wait... When you went from `1 != 2 != 1` to `1 != 1`, I thought that was from evaluating the first `1 != 2` to `1` (aka `True`), not from taking the first and third values and comparing them. Thanks for the clarification in your first edit, downvote retracted.